# Implement manual navigation for ng-bootstrap tabset

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Currently when I select the "Client" tab the content will open and when I select on the "Rate card" tab the content of the rate card will open, but navigation does not work when I use the arrows at the bottom. How do I apply navigation to arrows so when I select the arrow it moves to "Client" ,"Rate card","Burst"....[image]

```
<ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab title="Client">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ..content....
        </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
        </ngb-tabset>

        <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab title="Rate card">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ..content....
        </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
        </ngb-tabset>

        <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab title="Brust">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ..content....
        </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
        </ngb-tabset>

        <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab title="Contract Condition">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ..content....
        </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
        </ngb-tabset>

         <div class="actions">
                      <a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                      </a>
                      <a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                      </a>

          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **@ViewChild()** you can get the reference of the tabset.

Then on click of the buttons you can have a method which fires the following:

```
this.tabset.select(id);
```

To get set this id by adding an id to each ngb-tab:

```
 <ngb-tab id="tab-selectbyid2">
```

Then using your buttons and (click) events you can do the code in the .ts file to move between them all.

For example:

```
     <ngb-tabset #tabset>
    <ngb-tab id="client" title="Client">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ..content....
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>

  <ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Rate card" id="rate-card">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ..content....
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>

  <ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Brust">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ..content....
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>

  <ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Contract Condition" id="contact-contition">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ..content....
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>

  <div class="actions">
    <a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default" (click)="left();">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default" (click)="right();">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>

  </div>
```

And then in your .ts file do something to move between the id's:

```
  @viewChild() tabset: NgbTabset;

 left() {
    this.tabset.select('the id here');
  }

  right() {
    this.tabset.select('the id here');
  }
```

You can get more complex and for sure do this in multiple ways. But, hopefully, this gets you started.

You can find all this information here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples

Best of luck!

Comment: it is working now but for every click the id should keep changing

Comment: Maybe you can replicate your problem here: https://stackblitz.com, send me the link and I'd be happy to take a quick look

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

@ViewChild('tabset') tabset: NgbTabset;